# Why didn't change report style when modified qweb template?

Tags: python, odoo, qwebview

I'm a new user of QWeb. I want to create new report using qweb template at Odoo version 8. So, I added new .xml file in view folder and I declared that file in `__openerpy__.py` and `module_report.xml` file.

Firstly, it worked OK and outed report file. And then I modified some template or add more data... but I didn't get any changed report file.. same as origin file. why?

If you don't mind, please share me.
Thanks

Comment: Do you run odoo with `-u your_module_name` option? Otherwise when you change something in your module, it won't be reflected when running odoo.

Comment: Yeah, I'd already updated just like this. But it won't changed. I don't know why.